# Parsing JSON arrays of integers in Elixir

Tags: json, elixir

If I have a JSON object where the value of a key is an array of integers,  and *each integer* of the array *just happens to* correspond with the code point of a [printable ASCII character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart), is there any way that I can have Elixir interpret the array as just a plain list of integers and not as a char list?

I've used three different Elixir JSON parsers in an attempt to get a list of integers returned, but they all return the char representation of the list:

[`elixir-json`](https://github.com/cblage/elixir-json):

```
iex> JSON.decode!(~s({ "foo": [35, 35] }))
%{"foo" => '##'}
```

[`exjsx`](https://github.com/talentdeficit/exjsx):

```
iex> JSX.decode!(~s({ "foo": [35, 35] }))
%{"foo" => '##'}
```

[`poison`](https://github.com/devinus/poison):

```
iex> Poison.decode!(~s({ "foo": [35, 35] }))
%{"foo" => '##'}
```

What I would like is just `%{"foo" => [35, 35]}`.  Is this possible, or am I missing something?  If it's not possible, how should I be decoding this value from JSON into Elixir, and then how would I encode it back into a JSON array should I need to send the JSON on to some other external system?

**Edit**

Thanks to [michalmuskala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2919320/michalmuskala)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33978143/567863), I think something clicked, and then with some further investigation, I realised there was really nothing to worry about when it comes to the parsing JSON integer arrays in and out of Elixir:

```
iex> json = Poison.decode!(~s({ "foo": [35, 35] }))
%{"foo" => '##'}
iex> Poison.encode!(json)
"{\"foo\":[35,35]}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned result is perfectly fine and correct. `'##'` and `[35, 35]` is exactly the same thing in Elixir. It's just a different way to represent the same value.

```
iex> [35, 35] == '##'
true
iex> inspect [35, 35]
"'##'"
iex> inspect [35, 35], char_lists: :as_lists
"[35, 35]"
```

This is confusing at first, but there is a strong reason behind it. Majority of Erlang libraries use lists of chars (or charlists) as strings and not binaries as Elixir. For the ease of interoperability, if a list contains only printable characters it will be, by default, printed as a single quoted string. But this does not change what data is behind it - it's only a different representation of the same value.

Comment: I think the final sentence of your answer got something to finally click in my head, so thanks very much for that!

Answer (score 0):

It's a list:

```
iex(16)> '##' |> is_list
true
```

And you can do regular List operations on it:

```
iex(15)> '##' |> List.first
35
```